# enzyme test multiple render methods within same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component with multiple render methods. How can I test them all?
Using enzyme and jest with react.

Some pseudo code as an example of my component structure as the component is quiet large.

```js
class MyComponent extends Component{

  render1(){
    return(
      <div>render1</div>
    )
  }
  
  render2(){
    return(
      <div>render2</div>
    )
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
      <div>default</div>
    )
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

My test only covers `render()` it does not cover `render1()` or `render2()`.
It would seem enzyme looks at the default `render()` method?

```js
describe('MyComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    });
  
  it('MyComponent renders without crashing', () => {
      expect(wrapper.length).toBeTruthy();
  });
};
```

How can I include `render1()` and `render2()` in my coverage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only have one `render()` method, that's the method called when mounting components with `ReactDOM.render` or `enzyme.shallow`. How are the other rendering methods working for you?

Maybe you could do something like this, deciding which method to call from the `render()` method based on some prop or state:

```
class MyComponent extends Component{

  render1(){
    return(
      <div>render1</div>
    )
  }

  render2(){
    return(
      <div>render2</div>
    )
  }

  render(){
    const {shouldRender1, shouldRender2} = this.props;

    if (shouldRender1) {
      return this.render1();
    }

    if (shouldRender2) {
      return this.render2();
    }    

    return(
      <div>default</div>
    )
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Then your tests can look like this:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('MyComponent should render with render1 method', () => {
      wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent shouldRender1={true} />);
      expect(wrapper.length).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('MyComponent should render with render2 method', () => {
      wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent shouldRender2={true} />);
      expect(wrapper.length).toBeTruthy();
  });  

  it('MyComponent should render with default render method', () => {
      wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
      expect(wrapper.length).toBeTruthy();
  });    
};
```